# why i get button stretch width problem on IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

i have a button on my login page that results stretched in all IE browser versions.

Plese look at my live site black "LOGIN" button here:
[www.urbanclaim.com](http://www.urbanclaim.com)

this is the code i use for this button:   (view source code for the form structure)

```
<input style="margin-left:15px;"  type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="<?php echo JText::_('LOGIN') ?>" />
```

How can i solve this problem on ie?? thanks.

Comment: Please post the CSS code you're using for the .button class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button would work fine in IE8/9, but you have this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

which forces those browsers to emulate IE7, which is the only version that actually has a problem with your button.

To fix IE7 (and other versions of IE in IE7 mode..):

- On the `label` that is the parent of `.art-button-wrapper`, change `margin-left: 300px` to `padding-left: 300px`. Also add `display: block`. Make the same changes to the next `label`.

**See in IE7:** http://jsbin.com/akavef/3

```html
<!--
<label style="margin-left:300px;font-weight: bold; ">
-->
<label style="padding-left:300px;font-weight: bold; display:block ">
```